# Grab headers (just headers) from mail message in Perl

Tags: perl, parsing, email

I want to extract the headers of a mail message in Perl. I don't need the body and so I don't want to spend time parsing them.

[Email::Simple::Header](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Email-Simple-2.201/lib/Email/Simple/Header.pm) looks useful, but the typical instantiation involves parsing the whole email (inc. body). So I was thinking about slurping the headers like this

```
local $/ = "\n\n";
my $head = <>;
my $parsed = Email::Simple::Header->new($head);
```

Is this the most efficient way?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that this will save you any time. The body of the email doesn't get parsed by Email::Simple. The only time that it looks at the body is to split it from the header, by calling `Email::Simple::_split_head_from_body()`. This does pretty much the same thing that you are doing with `$/ = "\n\n"`, but handles different types of newlines better.

Unless you have profiling evidence that your program is spending tons and tons of time on unnecessary parsing of email bodies (whatever the heck it would be parsing in there), avoid premature optimization and just use the `Email::Simple` module normally.

Comment: Donig it that way is 33% slower, tested on a mailbox of 1,500 mixed-sized mails. Makes sense - why read all that data if you don't have to. Take your point about line breaks though...

Answer (score 1):

A zero-length line separates the header from the rest of the message.  Your perl script can simply read the incoming message up to the first zero-length line, and that's the header.

Comment: Yes, that's basically what my script does by setting `$/="\n\n"`. Also, can set it to `""` which will match any number of consecutive blank lines.